# Creating a lock on List<String> or Hastable<String,String>

Tags: java, locking

A List of String or Hastable of (String,String) type that contains certain values.
I have situation where multiple threads are running and I want each thread to use only one of the values from the above mentioned lists.

Example: 
List - Set1,Set2,Set3

If Thread1 is using Set1 and thread2 tries to use one of the values in the list, It should get only Set2 and Set3 as available. Set1 should be available when Thread1 is done.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: You could use a blocking queue. "BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe."

Answer (score 0):

you could implement it by locking on the `List` and removing/adding the appropriate `Set` before starting/after finishing the work:

```
public class ListLock {
    private List<Set<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    //initialize with some values
    public ListLock(List<Set<String>> availableValues) {
        this.list = availableValues;
    }

    //this will allow your Thread to get an available value. Your Thread needs to keep the selected value until the job is done and put it back
    public void synchronized aquireValue(Selector selector) {
        //this one is little bit tricky, you provide some interface, that has 1 method, that will call a "select" function on your Thread.
        Set<String> selected = selector.select(list);
        this.list.remove(selected);
    }

    //after job is done, put the value back in the list, so it's available for another Thread
    public void synchronized releaseValue(Set<String> value) {
        this.list.add(value);
    }
}
```

of course you could use generics to make this class more general

Comment: Can you please help me with Selector class please